# File not found: RibbonscontrolsLibrary.aero2 when debugging visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently working on a WPF project, it's been compiling properly but after i updated windows 10 to the latest build i can't compile the project anymore.

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' : 
'The assembly with display name 'RibbonControlsLibrary.Aero2' 
failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. 
The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'RibbonControlsLibrary.Aero2, 
Version=4.0.0.11019, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

this issue is also found here,

[Getting a FileNotFoundException for RibbonControlsLibrary.Aero2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568439/getting-a-filenotfoundexception-for-ribboncontrolslibrary-aero2)

i tried the deleting the .suo files as was suggested in the link above. and re-cloned the project but the problem still persists.

[image: references]

these are the references i've added to the project..

Any ideas?

EDIT:

the project works perfectly on a windows 7 machine, however this does not solve the issue. adding windowsPresentationFoundation.aero2 also did nothing
Another odd thing is that i can run the program without debugging it, but as soon as i start debugging it in visual studio 2017 i get the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in visual studio 2017,

it seems like visual studio 2017 has quite some bugs in it still. 
once i disabled XAML debugging 
by going  to  Debug -> options -> debugging -> general -> Untick Enable ui debugging tools for Xaml it magically started to work again